# Meteor: activating other templates through click?

Tags: javascript, meteor

By default I set one of my templates to `return false`. What I would like to do is have a click event that changes my previous template to `return true`. My code is as follows:

```
Template.mypage.helpers({
pagefunction(){ return false;}
});

Template.mypage.events({
'click #randomdiv': function(){
pagefunction(){ return true; }
} 
});
```

The command doesn't work, but demonstrates hopefully what I am trying to achieve. I would like `pagefunction` to return true when I click on a div that is within the same template.

Meanwhile, my HTML looks something along the lines of:

```
<template name="mypage">
    {{#if pagefunction}}
    {{> atemplate}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn that *event* into *state*. The most common way of doing this is using a `Session` variable.

```
Template.mypage.helpers({
  pagefunction(){ return Session.get('myState'); }
});

Template.mypage.events({
  'click #randomdiv': function(){
    Session.set('myState',true);
  } 
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean. For whatever reason however, I am unable to get my session variables stored. I have installed them `meteor add session`, so they do not show as undefined. However, they do not show on my Chrome resources console.

Comment: Come to think of it, I believe this is because the set storage debugger is typically for PHP, as the code itself works.

Answer (score 1):

try do this to solve session can't get,type the code at the beginning

var PAGE_KEY='page_key';

Session.setDefault(PAGE_KEY,false);